# "Only too happy" and related constructs in Spanish

Tags: traducción

How do we convey this sense in Spanish? Consider the following examples:

1. He was only too happy to oblige.
2. Do tell me...I'm only too curious to find out!

I am sure **solo** is not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me any English speaker if I'm wrong about the meaning of "only too (sth) to (do sth)"

The "only too" can't be translated directly, it is like a "quite".

The translations would be these:

```
Estaba encantado de ayudar.
Dímelo... tengo demasiada curiosidad para averiguarlo!
```

The last one has no sense to me, I'm not sure if I understand it.
Should that sentence be *Do tell me... I'm only too curious NOT to find out!* the translation would be easy:

```
Dímelo... ¡me muero de curiosidad!
Dímelo... ¡necesito saberlo!
```

Or, on a more literal form, although a bit weird (but still correct) would be:

```
Dímelo... ¡tengo demasiada curiosidad como para que no me lo digas!
```

Sources:

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1377777

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=138097

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the idiom *only too* means

> As a matter of fact; extremely: *I am only too glad to go.*
>
> Unfortunately; very: *It is only too likely to happen.*

So you are right, **solo** doesn't convey this meaning. I would go with the use of adverbs like  **muy, extremadamente, increiblemnente (algo)** and the like or expression similar to **entusiamado de/por (algo), ansioso por/de, *supercontento*, etc**.

> 1. Estaba **entusiamando/ encantado/ contentisimo/** de ayudar (o ansioso de ser de utilidad). Se **moria de ganas** por ayudar.
> 2. Dimelo, me **muero** de curiosidad/ tengo **muchisimas** ganas de saberlo / **no puedo aguantar** la curiosidad/ estoy **ansioso** por saberlo.

Answer (score 2):

*`only too`* is a rather curious English idiom. Of course, a word-by-word translation would be inappropriate, and there is no exact direct replacement. A general recipe in these cases would be: replace the English idiom by some approximate equivalent expression, and translate that. Then, we'd get most of the answers already posted, as well as some other ones:

```
[él] estaba completamente feliz de ser de ayuda (or: `totalmente`, `enteramente`)

Dímelo. Tengo, de verdad, demasiada curiosidad por saberlo.
```

Comment: What if one has to say something like, "It only gets better."?